# Need to upload multiple image on existing grid and also delete the image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have six boxes. In this box already have dummy image.I need to upload image and that placed to the top box one by one and need to delete also.

When we upload image using upload button, that placed on above div one by one. Currently when i try to add image that placed to all the six divs.

```
<div class="image-wrapper" style="display:flex;">
<div class="image-wrap">
<img id="img_0" src="assets/images/img1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
<img id="img_1" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
<img id="img_2" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
<img id="img_3" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
<img id="img_4" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
   </div>
 <div class="image-wrap">
 <img id="img_5" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
 </div>
 </div>

<div class="upload-btn">
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
<button class="btn">Upload a file1</button>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="">
</div>
</div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
     $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<div><span class=\"pip image-wrap\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">X</span>" +
            "</span></div>").insertAfter(".image-wrap");
          $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          });
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/QvtiAKg  This is the sample image which i need

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57967832/edit) your question and include desire result on question , not in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You are using generic selector `(".image-wrap")` hence image getting added to all div. You can access divs with index 0... n using `eq()` method and maintain last index in a variable so that you can calculate next index and add next image to the div.

No need to add remove button click handler each time when file loaded as this will cause issue and you will end with multiple click handler.  Better, put it outside using `.on()` so that dynamically added remove buttons will work.

See below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var imageIndex = 0; // variable to save index
   if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
     $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          var file = e.target;
          $("<div><span class=\"pip image-wrap\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result 
            + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">X</span>" +
            "</span></div>").insertAfter(".image-wrap:eq(" + imageIndex + ")"); // use index
          imageIndex++; // increment index by 1
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }

 // put remove action here for dynamically added image

  $(document).on("click",".remove",function(){
     $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are using a class selector with `insertAfter` its adding the image after every div having class `.image-wrap` instead use below code. Use the [last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) function to get the last `.image-wrap` and append it to that element. Below is a sample code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {

    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});

function uploadFile() {
  var files = $('#files')[0].files,
    filesLength = files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
    var f = files[i]
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
      var file = e.target;
      var emptyImg = $('img.img-fluid:not(.hasImage)');
      emptyImg[0].src = e.target.result;
      $(emptyImg[0]).addClass('hasImage');
      $(".remove").click(function() {
        var img = $(this).parent().find('img.hasImage')[0];
        img.src = '';
        $(img).removeClass('hasImage');
      });
    });
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-wrapper" style="display:flex;">
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img width="100" id="img_0" src="assets/images/img1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    <span class="remove">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img width="100" id="img_1" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
    <span class="remove">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img width="100" id="img_2" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
    <span class="remove">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img width="100" id="img_3" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
    <span class="remove">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img width="100" id="img_4" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
    <span class="remove">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <img width="100" id="img_5" src="assets/images/unloaded-img.png" class="img-fluid">
    <span class="remove">X</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="upload-btn">
  <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
    <button class="btn" onclick="uploadFile()">Upload a file1</button>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks :) I need when i upload image, that image replace with existing div.
Eg : https://imgur.com/QvtiAKg

Comment: @AnishSharma can you please explain a bit more.. I mean are you still facing issue? Also what exactly you need to happen.. if you can elaborate a bit more..

Comment: Thanku for your kind response. Please see the image. 
url :  https://imgur.com/QvtiAKg . Already we have six dummy div. we need to upload image on that div. When we upload image using "upload a file button", That replace dummy image tag inside the .image-wrap div.

Comment: Ok let me have a look. Will get back

Comment: Have updated the code according to this.. Please have a look. And do accept this as an answers if this solves your problem.